# CPLEX: Any Callbacks called per solution found while polishing?

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

What callbacks get called during polishing? More specifically, is there a callback that gets called for each new solution found during polishing?

I have some (old) code in C++ that uses a MIPInfoCallback and that gets called fine during B&B, but during polishing it doesn't seem to get called, even though polishing finds maybe 20 or 30 improved solutions.  The documentation states that callbacks get called normally during polishing, but it may be that the MIPInfoCallback only gets called before each node is explored, and in my case the polishing does not explore any extra nodes.

I tried switching to using an incumbent callback, but that seems to have a huge performance impact for me - just changing the type of my callback from a MIPInfoCallback to IncumbentCallback changes the time to get a first integer feasible solution from about 20 mins to over 3 hours (I was really just changing the type of the callback, leaving the body of the callback unchanged). I suspect that this is because use of an incumbent callback turns some things off in the search.

This is in C++ on Windows with CPLEX 12.1, but planning to update to 12.5 soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `CPXsetincumbentcallbackfunc` from the C callable library?  I haven't examined its behaviour when polishing, but it does permit the user to reject solutions at whim, so I imagine it must get called whenever the incumbent is about to get updated --- including during polishing.

Comment: CPXsetincumbentcallbackfunc is the C API equivalent of the IncumbentCallback in C++.

Comment: @DavidNehme: Yes, I failed to read the whole questoon.  Does registering an IncumbentCallback do anything precautionary?  I want to assume the time-to-first-solution change is just one of the vagaries of branch-and-bound search, but I'd want to rule out C++ library weirdness first.  (I ran away screaming from the C++ library when I found out about `EpLin`.  And I think I've seen it do some undocumented data checking by default.)